# How to turn off the reqtime parameter in magento checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

i am using a 3rd party payment gateway extension. I installed it successfully and all the things are working perfectly fine. While redirecting the products to the citrus official page.Then it is showing me the following error:-

```
Bad Request: Request is too old to be processed
```

I asked that problem to the citrus payment office and they replied me:-

This happened because of reqtime parameter where it takes System time. Kindly check server time from where you are testing it.

You can also remove reqtime as the same is non-mandatory.

I checked the time and date, it is taking the exact time and date. How can i turn off the required time parameter. Any help would be appreciated the most :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okays, so i got the answer. Just go to

```
app/code/community/CitrusPay/Moto/Block/Form/Pay.php
```

Search for reqtime and comment the below line and it will work :)

```
//$form->addField('ReqTime', 'hidden', array('name'=>'reqtime', 'value'=> (time()*1000)));
```

Problem solved :)